# what is the command to open encryped file of image, mp3,mp4 in terminal?

Tags: sudo, mp4, image-viewers

i tried using super user command in front of many commands like

> feh ,eog , VLC ,display

etc but nothing is shown . please help .!

Comment: With which application the files are encrypted?

Comment: by encfs command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To mount existing EncFS directories for use, repeat the command used to create them:

```
encfs ~/ENCRYPTED-DIRECTORY~/UNENCRYPTED-DIRECTORY
```

At this point, you will be prompted for the password.

For most users, no additional options are likely required.

However, EncFS does have a small set of options, which are described thoroughly in the man page.

Comment: so what to do i don't understand please explain

Comment: @Nishant: Decrypt the directory where you host the encrypted files first.
Then open the files, now decrypted, with the corresponding application.

Comment: sir my question is why i have to decrypt the file , is there any way of looking or accessing the encrypted files and also why sudo command  is failed to do so .

Comment: @Nishant: You report that the files were encrypted with encfs, encfs creates an encrypted virtual file system that stores encrypted data in the rootdir directory and makes the unencrypted data visible in the mountPoint directory.

The user must provide a password that is used to encrypt both the file names and their content.

Once the files are encrypted, so that the application that opens them can use them, it is necessary to decrypt the virtual file system that hosts them and thus make the files accessible to the application.

The sudo command has nothing to do with this procedure.